# Google apps script clear content function error "you are trying to edit protected cell"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Script given below was has been working for 7 months. It suddenly started giving error saying that you are trying to edit protected cell. All the cells that I was trying to clear were an exception in protected sheet.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRangeList(['B28:H28', 'E21:E24', 'I18', 'H15:I15', 'C8:E8', 'C7:E7']).activate()
.clear({contentsOnly: true,skipFilteredRows: true});
```

Then after when I replaced

```
.clear({contentsOnly: true,skipFilteredRows: true});
```

with

```
.clearContent();
```

It started working again.

I just want to know that what could have caused this issue as it was working before without any issue.

Comment: I don't think that we can tell why the script was working before and suddenly stop working because the lack of details. Maybe looking at the Version History you could find what change causes the problem. P.S. Using `.activate()` usually is not necessary and only affects negatively the script performance.

Comment: @Rubén I am pretty sure nothing changed on spreadsheet as there were about 30 different spreadsheets that stopped working at the same time and those spreadsheets had nothing in common. Here is example spreadsheet you can try
[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BejWs7pFnAinyB92WCd6k4mNoBvnCgniW9geqRi-hqU/edit#gid=0) 
Cells'A1:A10' are an exception from protection on sheet1 and when anyone else other than owner try to use the function using test button which is trying to clear cells ['A1','A5'] it gives error "Exception: You are trying to edit a protected cell or object".

Comment: @BalkarBrar I'm having the same problem except I was using `.clearContent()` and `.clear()` doesn't work either.  This is happening on multiple Sheets that have been working for months.

Comment: It looks like this is an open bug that they are working on.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187340556 I was able to fix my issue by adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before clearing the contents using `.clearContent()`